# Logs from custom logger are not being written to the logfile using config file for logging

Tags: python, file, logging, stdout, python-logging

I'm using Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module to log an installation script. The logs are being printed to the console, but the log file is being created empty. I'm loading the conf from an external file.

```
import logging
import logging.config

LOGGING_CONF = 'logging.conf'
logging.config.fileConfig(LOGGING_CONF, disable_existing_loggers=False,
                          defaults={'log_filename': 'install.log'})
```

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger('install')
self.logger.info("install()")
```

The config file `logging.conf` has the following config

```
[loggers]
keys=root,install

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_install]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=test.install
propagate=0

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('%(log_filename)s','w')

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

The `install.log` is always created empty. No matter what handler I select in the `logging.conf` it only writes to the console.

Comment: `qualname=test.install` => `self.logger = logging.getLogger('test.install')`. If you are seeing messages on the console with this config, you are not logging to the configured logger, but to a newly created one that propagates to root.

Comment: @shmee this is the right answer, I suggest you make an actual answer of it. If the code is changed to `self.logger = logging.getLogger('test.install')` then it will log to `install.log`.